# What is the possible orders of $a?$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $H\lhd G,a\in G$ such that $|aH|=3$ in $G/H$ and $|H|=10.$ What is the possible orders of $a?$

$$MY ~TRY$$

$(aH)^3=H\implies a^3\in H\implies|a^3||10\implies|a^3|=1,2,5,10$

$|a^3|=1\implies a^3=e\implies |a||3\implies |a|=3$ (since $|a|=1\implies a\in H\implies |aH|=1!$)

$|a^3|=2\implies a^6=e\implies |a||6\implies |a|=3$ (since $|a|=2\implies a^2\in H\implies |aH|\le2!$)

$|a^3|=5\implies a^{15}=e\implies|a||15\implies |a|=3,5,15$

$|a^3|=10\implies a^{30}=e\implies|a||30\implies |a|=3,5,6,10,15,30\implies|a|=3,6,10,15,30$ (since $|a|=5\implies |a^3|=5$)

The order of $a$ must be a multiple of the order of $aH$ so the possibilities are $3,6,15,30.$

***Can this list be further redueced?***

Comment: The order of $a$ must be a multiple of the order of $aH$ in $G/H$, since $aH$ is the image of $a$ under a homomorphism (or just by calculation). So this means that some of your numbers are not possible.

Comment: Thank you @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: The list cannot be further reduced. Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/(30)$, and $H = \langle 3\rangle$. Let $a \in \{1, 2, 5, 10\}$ to get the orders $30,15,6,3$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Did you mean to say $|a|\in\{1, 2, 5, 10\}$ ?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath No. I don't distinguish notationally between the integers and their residue classes in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ unless I need to consider both at the same time.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ohh! Then its clear to me.